# Way to configure RAID 5 for dual-boot windows 7 and ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

What's the best way to configure RAID 5 for dual-boot windows and ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a RAID card that allows RAID 5 and supports both Ubuntu and Windows, then, use its own configuration utility to configure the RAID, and then install Windows and Ubuntu in the usual way, and in that order.

Hardware RAID should present itself to the OS as a simple drive. it should be invisible to the OS running underneath it, with the exception of status/monitoring programs.

Comment: Thanks William, how do I determine from the RAID card's specs if it supports both ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: Also, I haven't been able to find any material online of anyone whose actually done dual boot RAID with windows and linux at the hardware level.  Are you sure this is even possible?

Comment: @LedZeppelin Absolutely yes - The purpose of hardware raid is that the "magic" happens at the hardware level and it just presents itself to the OS as a regular/normal hard drive - it doesn't have a clue that it is raided. The reason you can't find sources is because hardly anyone would do it (I can't think of a good reason) - RAID, especially 5 is pretty much just used for servers and they would only be on one OS, they wouldn't dual boot - but, it doesn't mean it isn't possible. As for finding out what supports it, just look at the manufacturers website for specifications.

Comment: Sorry for not checking back on this answer.  Thanks so much, very informative and I came to the same conclusion as you did why there are no examples of dual boot RAID 5.